# Composition of itertools function in python

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, composition

How can I combine/chain itertools functions?

For example, I'd like to combine `itertools.counter` with `itertools.repeat` so as to have a function 'counter_repeat' that output twice each value of the counter.

The function would be called like that:

```
count_twice = counter_repeat(start=1, step=1, repeat=2)
```

The output would be:

```
>>> next(count)
<<< 1
>>> next(count)
<<< 1
>>> next(count)
<<< 2
>>> next(count)
<<< 2
>>> next(count)
<<< 3
(...)
```

FYI, I know how to write the function myself :

```
def counter_repeat(start=0, step=1, re=1):
    n = start
    while True:
        for i in range(re):
            yield n
        n += step
count_rep = counter_repeat(1, 1, 2)
```

What I'd like is to  know how to compose/chain the itertools functions.

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful or not, but your specific example could be also written as `chain.from_iterable(map(partial(repeat, times=2), count(1)))`

Comment: You can try something like this https://pastebin.com/MCM4ysLB